# Why does the label control element does not wrap onto multiple lines after I select that option

Tags: ios, interface-builder, storyboard, uilabel

I have a long label that spans multiple lines and I can not get it to wrap the text. I selected 5 lines and wrap-text option, but for some reason it is not happening. Any idea how to do that? :)

I am attaching the screen shot.[image]

Comment: From your screenshot, you're not using Xcode 4.5 prerelease... not wise to tag your question [ios6] in that case.

Comment: @BoltClock I didn't realize I was using that version of xcode. Is the version of my xcode corresponding to the ios version? I thoubht I was on ios5 and accidentally mis-labeled ios6

Comment: Ah, in that case you can add the right tag back in. I was afraid people were going to assume you were using beta software, and start yelling at you about NDAs and stuff.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you paste text into a label, interface builder automatically makes it wide enough to accomodate the text. Just resize your label to a smaller width; easiest to do in the size inspector on the right (the ruler icon). Try a width of 300px.

[image]

Comment: thanks Jesse, I am trying to mess with it now, but I am not sure which is the size inspector.  How do I use that tool? Also, when I try to resize, it isn't letting me get it to  multiple lines

Comment: @Genadinik I have added a screenshot to the above answer to show you where the size inspector is.